# Wrong Auto Login with Automation Anywhere

Tags: authentication, automationanywhere

I have a problem trying to schedule a task with Automation Anywhere 10.5.

I've actually activated the Auto login option at AAE Client but when the computer is locked and the task is suppose to start **the computer doesn't login and the task starts normally as in background without unlocking the computer**.

The problem with it is that we can only run tasks that normally would run on background (tasks that don't need to activate windows and perform operations like clicks or object cloning).

Example: I schedule a task that shows a simple Messagebox but when apparently it doesn't run. Then, I log in to the computer and I can see the messagebox active.

Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

My team has hit a few snags on this previously. If you haven't solved this yet - please utilize the following link:
http://www.automationanywhere.com/techsupport/Customers/Support/Utility/Autologin_Diagnose_Fix_Utility.zip

I received this from an AA employee as well as a best practice document. The utility tool should alert you of any practices you're not currently adhering to and resolve them if it can.

Please let me know if you need additional assistance.

Comment: Hi Caleb,Thanks for responding. I wasn't able to see the link you shared. It says error 404 Not Found. I still have the error of auto login.

Comment: I would recommended reaching out to their customer support to receive it. Like I said, the autologin will either tell you what you need to do or go ahead and fix it for you. I apologize - that link was working at the time I had sent it